# A simple circle problem

Tags: circles

There is a big circle of radius 20cm and a smaller circle 100 cm away from it of radius 5cm now imagine these two to be 2 tires  connected by a chain , where the  bigger one completes one rotation how many rotation will small complete??

Any idea how to Solve this??

Comment: When you say "$100$cm away," do you mean the distance between the centers, or the distance between the actual circles?

Comment: How is the chain connected? How is the distance measured (center-to-center or border-to-border)? What have you done so far?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews i think 100 cm would be = when taken by radius or from bottom...yeah..possible, a taunt.May be related to RPM

Comment: If this is a classical "linked wheels" problem, the things to ask yourself are how do the circumferences of the two wheels compare, and how far will the chain (or belt) move when the large wheel turns one completely?  (And, yes, if the two wheels are connected by the chain or belt without any slippage, the distance the wheels are separated by is irrelevant.  In fact, the two wheels could touch each other at a tangent point without any chain at all and the answer would be the same.)

Comment: @AlexR i tried up taking their RPM's and dividing...Cannot get it though

Comment: @RecklessReckoner If they are connected, then the smaller one will turn only after 20*5 turns of the 1st one.Then how to relate it with a single round?

Comment: Don't the two wheels _and_ the connecting chain all turn together at the same rate?  For the large tire to turn once means a point on its circumference has moved $ \ 2 \cdot \pi \cdot 20 \ $ cm., so every point on the connecting chain _and_ on the smaller tire will have moved by the same amount.  How many times will the small tire have turned if a point on _its_ circumference has moved by $ \ 2 \cdot \pi \cdot 20 \ $ cm. ?

Comment: @RecklessReckoner 4 times?

Comment: @RecklessReckoner or just 1 time :O

Comment: A point on the circumference of the large time has traveled $ \ 40 \pi \ $ cm. after one rotation.  So must everything else in the system connected to that tire.  So the small tire must turn four times for a point on its edge to circle by the same distance.  (This illustrates a general principle in the design of mechanical linkages and gear trains...)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9787/discussion-between-joey-rohan-and-recklessreckoner)

Comment: "100 cm away from it" This information is almost useless.. don't worry about it ;) ... 20cm*(some variables)/5cm*(some variables) ... some variables cancel out.. 20/5 = 4... 4 spins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the chain moves by some amount $s$ (measured somewhere between the two wheels) then
$$r_{\rm big}\cdot \phi_{\rm big}=s=r_{\rm small}\cdot \phi_{\rm small}\ ,$$
where $\phi_{\rm big}$ and $r_{\rm big}$ are the turning angle and the radius of the big wheel; and similarly for the small wheel. It follows that
$$\phi_{\rm small}={r_{\rm big}\over r_{\rm small}}\cdot \phi_{\rm big}=4\phi_{\rm big}\ .$$
Therefore the small wheel will complete four full turns when the big wheel completes one.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming they are connected in a $1:1$ means of distance (i.e. a fixed chain on a cog), you have to get the circumference via
$$s = 2\pi r$$
where $r$ is the radius of the cog. The number is then computed by
$${\rm rot}_{\rm small} \cdot s_{\rm small} = {\rm rot}_{\rm big} \cdot s_{\rm big}$$

Comment: so the rot by small wheel is simply 20/5?

Comment: Yes:  if everything is moving together and the small tire has one-quarter the diameter (and thus one-quarter the circumference) of the large time, then it will rotate four times as rapidly.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner so here r should be the radius of circles right? Why the cog?

Comment: The cog as an example of lossles transfer. A rubber band would have friction loss etc, wich would not guarantee the $1:1$ tranmission rate